# Logic regarding waiting for user input before iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, dom

I have made some type of word-guessing game based on showing description of some word to user and comparing user entered value with the pre-defined word. The logic I have implemented is as follows:

1. In global scope, there is an array with objects inside (eg. arr = [ {desc1, word1}, {desc2, word2}......]
2. On 'start' button click, I want to show description(desc) of first object. (eg. arr[0].desc )
3. The user enters some word and presses 'submit' button.
4. On 'submit' press, the program checks if user entered word is the same as the word inside array (word1 on first run). The program then does random stuffs based on comparison results.
5. The program then iterates over to next object in array and continues this till last object.
6. Then it shows final results after the iteration ends.

> The issue I am having is that either the loop runs rampant
>   (infinte-loop) or directly goes to the end results without doing
>   anything.

I don't know how to make the program wait/stop until the user enters something and presses submit to then iterate over the loop. Can't use if-else loop either as else will always be true unless I use some sort of setTimeout() to give user enough time to enter stuffs but it seems clunky and just some band-aid method.

> Is there any other logic in solving this kind of problem? Thank You.

Comment: 5) You say that the program iterates over the array and continues until the last object.
What is the loop doing. What do you expect it to do when you say that it goes (infinite-loop) or directly to the end?

Is the program supposed to loop through the array prompting the user for words based on the descriptions?

Comment: yes the program loops through the array, prints out the description in a box and has another space for user to guess word. Then another conditional inside the loop compares user-entered word with the word in array and shows some results. However the issue is the loop doesn't care about the inside events and either keeps looping forever or iterates upto the last object and goes to the end. User has no way to enter stuffs before loop ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two easy solutions.

1) Use [prompt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) to find retrieve user input (it stops the script until user answers)

Example:

```
var questions = [...]; // assuming content objects look like {word:"...", description:"..."}

for(var i in questions){
    var userInput = prompt( questions[i]["description"] ); // prompt() stops the script until user answers

    if(userInput == questions[i]["word"]){  // compare user input with value from object
        // [handle correct guess]
    } else {
        // [handle incorrect guess]
    }
}
// [Game Ended]
```

2) If don't want to use the prompt dialog, rather than displaying questions in a loop, I recommend displaying only one question at a time and storing the index of displayed option in an extra global variable. In the handler of your submit button, increment the index and ask the next question.

Example:

```
var questions= [ ... ];
var currentIndex = 0;

function askNextQuestion(){
    if(currentIndex < questions.length){
        var currentQuestion = questions[currentIndex];
        // [Display the question]
    } else {
        // [Game Ended]
    }
}
function start(){      // call this function from Start handler
    currentIndex = 0;  // set question index to 0
    askNextQuestion(); // ask the question
}
function submitPressed(){ // call this function from Submit handler
    // [handle answer]
    currentIndex++;      // go to next question
    askNextQuestion();   // ask the question
}
```

Comment: the second one was what I was looking for :)  I made mistake by putting all event-handlers inside a single loop(that iterates through array) which caused the loop to either end prematurely or loop forever. thanks a lot :D